# C++ Memory Leak With Optional Parameter

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, optional-parameters

The following code causes memory leak. Does anyone have any idea why?

(I am running the code, and then looking at Windows Task Manager/Processes Tab/Memory Column and see that it goes up. I am using a GCC compiler.)

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> f() {
    vector<int> v;

    int ctr = 8;
    while(ctr--) v.push_back(ctr);

    return v;
}

void g(vector<int> v = {}) {   // strangely enough, no leaks if defined 
    v = f();                   // like void g(vector<int> v = vector<int>{})
}

int main() {
    int ctr = 999999;
    while(ctr--) g();
}
```

Comment: only one observation, shouldn't you use int main() instead of void main()

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Are you sure you copied it exactly? No leaks if void g(vector<int> v = **vector<int>** {})

Comment: @Kemal Yes, I know how to copy-paste.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Just wanted to make sure. :-) Maybe it has to do with my compiler. Using a GCC.

Comment: @Kemal Yes, it is possible that it is compiler/version dependent. Too bad that I can't test on GCC, since the only compiler that's available for me is MSVC.

Comment: Even I cannot reproduce. Tryed with g++ (4.9.2) and clang++ (3.5.0) in a amd64 debian 8.0 platform. Valgrind say "in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks - total heap usage: 3,999,996 allocs, 3,999,996 frees, 59,999,940 bytes allocated - All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible"

Comment: @max66 upgraded my compiler to GCC 4.9.2 now. Problem solved. Thank you.